# Convert a 3D array to 2D array based on dictionary

Tags: python, numpy

This is my code where I convert a color image into grayscale based on a dictionary mapping

```
M, N = color.shape[:2]
out = np.zeros((M, N))
for i in range(M):
    for j in range(N):
        out[i][j] = color2ind[tuple(color[i,j,:])]
```

The dictionary for example is:

```
color2ind = {(128, 128, 128): 6, 
(0, 128, 128): 2, 
(128, 0, 128): 1, 
(128, 0, 0): 7, 
(128, 128, 0): 5, 
(0, 0, 128): 3, 
(0, 128, 0): 4, 
(0, 0, 0): 0}
```

What is the more pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: `out` is a 2D array, not 1D. Is your code wrong, or your title?

Comment: Also, NumPy generally has different idioms than Python in general; it might be more "pythonic" to use a comprehension instead of an explicit loop mutating an output array, but that would probably be less "numpythonic".

Comment: Also, given the choice between using 2MB for a 128x128x128 array for blazing-fast speed, a sparse array for cheap storage and medium speed, or a dict for simple code?

Comment: How do you implement this first option (128x128x8 array)? Will it be out = mapping[color]?

Comment: 128x128x128. It's just an array where `c[r, g, b]` is the index—exactly the same as the dict, except that it takes up more memory (or, for a sparse array, is slower). So, why would you do it? Because you can vectorize indexing an array, but as far as I know (someone might prove me wrong) you can't vectorize indexing a dict (except by using `np.vectorize(d.get)` or the like, which only gives you the syntax, not the performance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dict is a map from keys to values. A NumPy array can also act as a map from
keys to values. For example,

```
In [11]: dct = {3:40, 2:30, 1:20, 0:10}

In [9]: arr = np.array([10,20,30,40])

In [12]: arr[3]
Out[12]: 40

In [13]: dct[3]
Out[13]: 40
```

The dict is more flexible -- it's keys can be any hashable object. The array
must be indexed by integers. But the array may be more appropriate in a NumPy
setting since the array can itself be indexed by an integer array:

```
In [8]: index = np.array([3,2,1,0])

In [10]: arr[index]
Out[10]: array([40, 30, 20, 10])
```

whereas the equivalent using a dict requires a loop:

```
In [17]: [dct[i] for i in index]
Out[17]: [40, 30, 20, 10]
```

Integer indexing is much faster than dict lookups in a loop:

```
In [19]: %timeit arr[index]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 201 ns per loop

In [20]: %timeit [dct[i] for i in index]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.63 µs per loop
```

This rough equivalence between dicts and NumPy arrays is the one insight which
motivates the method below. The rest of the code is there simply to overcome
obstacles such as not having integer keys (you'll see this is solved by using
`np.unique`'s `return_inverse=True` to obtain unique labels which are integers.)

---

Suppose you have this setup:

```
import numpy as np

color = np.array([
    [  0,   0,   0],
    [128,   0, 128],
    [  0, 128, 128],
    [  0,   0, 128],
    [  0, 128,   0],
    [128, 128,   0],
    [128, 128, 128],
    [128,   0,   0],], dtype='uint8').reshape(-1,2,3)

color2ind = {(128, 128, 128): 6, 
             (0, 128, 128): 2, 
             (128, 0, 128): 1, 
             (128, 0, 0): 7, 
             (128, 128, 0): 5, 
             (0, 0, 128): 3, 
             (0, 128, 0): 4, 
             (0, 0, 0): 0}
```

Then:

```
def rgb2int(arr):
    """
    Convert (N,...M,3)-array of dtype uint8 to a (N,...,M)-array of dtype int32
    """
    return arr[...,0]*(256**2)+arr[...,1]*256+arr[...,2]

def rgb2vals(color, color2ind):
    int_colors = rgb2int(color)
    int_keys = rgb2int(np.array(color2ind.keys(), dtype='uint8'))
    int_array = np.r_[int_colors.ravel(), int_keys]
    uniq, index = np.unique(int_array, return_inverse=True)
    color_labels = index[:int_colors.size]
    key_labels = index[-len(color2ind):]

    colormap = np.empty_like(int_keys, dtype='uint32')
    colormap[key_labels] = color2ind.values()
    out = colormap[color_labels].reshape(color.shape[:2])
    return out

print(rgb2vals(color, color2ind))
```

yields

```
[[0 1]
 [2 3]
 [4 5]
 [6 7]]
```

(The numbers are in order; `color` was picked so the answer is easy to check.)

---

Here is a benchmark showing rgb2vals, which uses NumPy indexing, is much faster
than using a double for-loop:

```
def using_loops(color, color2ind):
    M, N = color.shape[:2]
    out = np.zeros((M, N))
    for i in range(M):
        for j in range(N):
            out[i][j] = color2ind[tuple(color[i,j,:])]
    return out
```

---

```
In [295]: color = np.tile(color, (100,100,1))

In [296]: (rgb2vals(color, color2ind) == using_loops(color, color2ind)).all()
Out[296]: True

In [297]: %timeit rgb2vals(color, color2ind)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.74 ms per loop

In [298]: %timeit using_loops(color, color2ind)
1 loops, best of 3: 751 ms per loop
```

---

The first step is to reduce `color` to a 2-dimensional array by converting every (r,g,b) triplet to a single int:

```
In [270]: int_colors = rgb2int(color)
In [270]: int_colors
Out[270]: 
array([[      0, 8388736],
       [  32896,     128],
       [  32768, 8421376],
       [8421504, 8388608]], dtype=uint32)
```

Now we do the same for the (r,g,b) triplet keys in the `color2ind` dict:

```
In [271]: int_keys = rgb2int(np.array(color2ind.keys(), dtype='uint8'))
In [271]: int_keys
Out[271]: 
array([8388608, 8421504, 8388736, 8421376,     128,       0,   32768,
         32896], dtype=uint32)
```

Concatenate these two arrays and then use `np.unique` to find the inverse index:

```
In [283]: int_array = np.r_[int_colors.ravel(), int_keys]

In [284]: uniq, index = np.unique(int_array, return_inverse=True)

In [285]: index
Out[285]: array([0, 5, 3, 1, 2, 6, 7, 4, 4, 7, 5, 6, 1, 0, 2, 3])

In [286]: uniq
Out[286]: 
array([      0,     128,   32768,   32896, 8388608, 8388736, 8421376,
       8421504], dtype=uint32)
```

`uniq` holds the unique values in `int_colors` and `int_keys`.
`index` holds the index values such that `uniq[index] = int_array`:

```
In [265]: (uniq[index] == int_array).all()
Out[265]: True
```

Once we have `index` we are golden. The values in `index` are like labels, each label is associated to a particular color. The first `color.size` items in `index` are labels for the colors in `color`, the last `len(color2ind)` items in `index` are the labels for the keys in `color2ind`.

```
color_labels = index[:int_colors.size]
key_labels = index[-len(color2ind):]
```

Now all we need is to make an array, `colormap` with the values in `color2ind.values()`, such that  the key labels map to the values:

```
colormap[key_labels] = color2ind.values()
```

By placing the values in `color2ind` at the index positions equal to the
associated key labels, we create a colormap array which is can in effect act
like a dict. `colormap[color_labels]` maps the color labels to `color2ind` values, which is exactly what we want:

```
out = colormap[color_labels].reshape(color.shape[:2])

In [267]: out
Out[267]: 
array([[7, 6],
       [1, 5],
       [3, 0],
       [4, 2]], dtype=uint32)
```

Answer (score 0):

By using logical indexing, you'll get a much quicker result. Here's one way you could achieve that:

```
>>> A  # display test array that has all possibilities
array([[[   0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,  128],
        [   0,  128,    0],
        [   0,  128,  128]],

       [[ 128,    0,    0],
        [ 128,    0,  128],
        [ 128,  128,    0],
        [ 128,  128,  128]]])

>>> B = (A[:,:,2]*4 + A[:,:,1]*2 + A[:,:,0])/128 # Notice the typical binary tricks
>>> B
array([[ 0,  4,  2,  6],
       [ 1,  5,  3,  7]])
>>> color2ind = {7: 6, 3:2, 5:1, 4:7, 6:5, 1:3, 2:4, 0:0} # reinterpretation as binary coded of your map
>>> C = np.empty_like(B)
>>> for k,v in color2ind.items():
...    C[B == k] = v
...
>>> C
array([[ 0,  7,  4,  5],
       [ 3,  1,  2,  6]])
```

Caveat: it assumes the only values present in your array are 0 and 128, which it would appear from your own code and your color2ind map.

Edit: abarnert's comment is true though. Indexing an `m x n x 3` array is still very fast and probably much more ideal for further image processing than this color coded 2D array. Still, if this is really what you want, this is not such a bad approach.